# weka.classifiers.functions.LinearRegression cannot be cast to weka.classifiers.meta.EnsembleSelection

Tags: java, classification, weka

I want to copy classifier generated by `Bagging` method to `EnsembleSelection` classifier directly without copy it in the file  below my code:

```
data.setClassIndex(datamoufi.numAttributes()-1);
Bagging B=new Bagging ();

// runClassifier(B, argv);
String options = (" java weka.classifiers.meta.ClassificationViaRegression -W weka.classifiers.functions.LinearRegression \\\n" +
                  " -x 2 -I 4 -- -S 1");
String[] optionsArray = options.split(" ");
B.setOptions(optionsArray);
B.setCalcOutOfBag(true);
B.buildClassifier(data);

EnsembleSelection classifier=null;

classifier = (EnsembleSelection) B.getClassifier();
```

the error is :

> ClassCastException: weka.classifiers.functions.LinearRegression cannot be cast to weka.classifiers.meta.EnsembleSelection

Answer (score 1):

[LinearRegression](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/classifiers/functions/LinearRegression.html) class hierarchy:

[image: Object-AbstractClassifier-LinearRegression]

[EnsembleSelection](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.packages/ensembleLibrary/weka/classifiers/meta/EnsembleSelection.html) class hierarchy:

[image: Object-AbstractClassifier-RandomizableClassifier-EnsembleSelection]

EnsembleSelection is not an ancestor of LinearRegression, so casting is not possible. Their nearest common ancestor is [weka.classifiers.AbstractClassifier](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/classifiers/AbstractClassifier.html), from `weka.classifiers` package. So you can cast to it.